# Koin : how inject a sharedViewModel in WorkManager?

Tags: android-viewmodel, koin

I want to inject shared viewModel in WorkManager. But

```
by sharedViewModel<MyModel>()
```

is not resolved.

```
class MyCoroutineWorker(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters):CoroutineWorker(context, params)
   , KoinComponent {
override val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.IO
val gameListModel by sharedViewModel<MyModel>()

override suspend fun doWork(): Result = coroutineScope {
    Result.success()
}
}
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As per KOIN standard, you can't share `ViewModel` in different context.

If you want to share `ViewModel` in `WorkManage`, it is not possible in koin.

`SharedViewModel` only works in same context like `Activity` and it's nested fragments.

You can check how sharedViewModel feature works, here:

https://insert-koin.io/docs/2.0/documentation/koin-android/index.html#_shared_viewmodel

Answer (score 2):

As @Pranay said, it is not made for usecases like that!

Because `WorkManager` uses `JobSchedulers` and other components under the hood. And also when the work is executed, there's no promise that the Koin will be initialized before starting the work.

Also, If you want to pass some parameters to your work, you should consider passing them to the `Worker` implementation class or store them to `SharedPreferences` and accessing them when the work is executed

Comment: Is there any solution for this problem? I have the same problem in my library and sometimes Koin is null. I use a work manager to read and send data from a room database. And some specific case koin is null.